# How to Interrupt or Cancel a Spring Integration Java DSL flow?

Tags: java, spring-integration, dsl, cancellation

Contemplating implementation of a feature wherein a `JdbcRepositoryHandler` (implemnting `MessageHandler`) might listen for an outside event (e.g., `CancelRunEvent`).

I think I'd use Spring' `ApplicationEvent` support to publish an event via a REST controller endpoint.  And I would guess I'd have the aforementioned handler implement `ApplicationListener` to listen for a particular event?

The question is: **if the handler is saturated with messages it needs to process, how would I signal termination of all subsequent messages** that may have emanated upstream e.g., from a `FileSplitter`?

While I could easily construct a condition to be checked before calling a method responsible e.g., for a persistence operation (based on some state received from the `CancelRunEvent`), **how could I interrupt the flow entirely**?

For illustrative purposes, imagine a flow like:

```
@Bean
protected IntegrationFlow s3ChannelFlow() {
    // @see http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/files.html#file-reading
    // @formatter:off
    return IntegrationFlows
        .from(s3Channel())
        .enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerFunction(RunStats.FILE_TOKEN, f -> UUID.randomUUID().toString()))
        .channel(runStatsChannel())
        .transform(new FileToInputStreamTransformer())
        .split(new FileSplitter())
        .transform(new JsonToObjectViaTypeHeaderTransformer(new Jackson2JsonObjectMapper(objectMapper), typeSupport))
        .publishSubscribeChannel(p -> p.subscribe(persistenceSubFlow()))
        .get();
    // @formatter:on
}

@Bean
protected IntegrationFlow persistenceSubFlow() {
    // @formatter:off
    return f -> f
            // @see http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#agg-and-group-to
            .aggregate(a -> a
                    .correlationStrategy(new HeaderAttributeCorrelationStrategy(RunStats.FILE_TOKEN))
                    .releaseStrategy(new MessageCountReleaseStrategy(persistenceBatchSize))
                    .sendPartialResultOnExpiry(true)
                    .expireGroupsUponCompletion(true)
                    .groupTimeoutExpression(persistenceBatchReleaseTimeoutMillis)
            )
            .handle(new JdbcRepositoryHandler(typeSupport, metricRegistry, runStatsRepository));
    // @formatter:on
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you mean or why you would need the `JdbcRepositoryHandler` to manage this rather than some other `ApplicationListener`.

Your flow is running on some thread upstream of `s3Channel()`. Depending on what that is, you could `stop()` the message source and no new messages will be emitted after the current one (or ones if it's multi-threaded).

However, you may (likely will) end up with a partial aggregation sitting in memory until the group times out.

Comment: The handler itself needn't implement ApplicationListener, you're right about that. Just was wondering where I could register that listener with the flow? The origination of flow is an HTTP endpoint. The request parameters feed another MessageProducingHandler that reads from a S3 bucket and syncs to a local file system and whose output channel is the S3 channel in flow above.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "register that listener with the flow"; it's not really part of the flow, it's controlling it - see the [EIP Control Bus](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/ControlBus.html) and [Spring Integration's implementation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#control-bus). Your listener can either stop your s3 message producer directly, or send a message to the control bus to do so.

Comment: Thanks Gary for revealing that bit and the hint. "Notifying flow to terminate processing" might be a better way to describe my intentions. I find something new everyday in Spring to delight.